# Add a subquery to SELECT'd columns in a dynamic query

Tags: 7, database

I have a query I want to run through Drupal 7's DB API as a dynamic query where a subquery needs to be a column of data.

For example:

```
SELECT a, b, (
  SELECT x, y
    FROM table
    WHERE table.x = 'value') as c
FROM table_2
WHERE table_2.a = 'value_2'
```

How can I perform this through the Drupal 7's DB API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building a dynamic query, the method [`SelectQuery::addExpression()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x) will let you add a SQL subquery expression to the list of selected columns:

```
$query = db_select('table_2', 't2')
  ->fields('t2', array('a', 'b'))
  ->condition('t2.a', 'value_2');

$sub_query = "(SELECT x, y
  FROM table
  WHERE table.x = 'value')";

$query->addExpression($sub_query, 'c');
$results = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `db_query()`

```
$result = db_query(
  'SELECT a, b, (
    SELECT x, y
    FROM {table}
    WHERE table.x = :value1) as c
  FROM {table_2} AS table_2
  WHERE table_2.a = :value2',
  array(
    ':value1' => 'value',
    ':value2' => 'value_2',
  )
);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this was in the context of a dynamic query, but yeah this method works too. Thanks!